# Javascript recursivity check

Tags: javascript, recursion

Is there a built-in way to check if a javascript function has been called recursively (directly or indirectly)?

By recursively, I mean that the function could be anywhere in the recursion chain (the function doesn't have to be the direct invoker).

**EDIT**

Obviously, there's no built-in way to achieve what I want to do.  I though the plan B would be easy to implement so I came up with this solution (similar to Paolo answer):

```
    function checkRecursion() {

        var f = arguments.callee.caller;

        var caller = f;
        while (caller) {
            caller = caller.caller;
            if (caller === f) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    };
```

This function is working perfectly if you try to search the first recursive level.

```
    function fA() {
        if (checkRecursion()) {
            alert("End of recursion");
        }
        else {
            fB();
        }

    }

    function fB() {
        fA();
    }

    fA();
```

However, if you need to perform the same check on a function executed after an other recursion, you'll end up into an infinite loop:

```
    var count = 0;

    function fA() {
        if (checkRecursion()) {
            //I should get here but I get stuck in the checkRecursion()
            alert("End of recursion");
        }
        else {
            fB();
        }

    }

    function fB() {

        if (count > 2) {
            fA();
        } else
        {
            count++;
            fC();
        }

    }

    function fC() {
        fB();
    }

    fA();
```

For some reason, the fB caller is fC, and the fC caller is fB so I can't travel back to the fA function as a caller of fB.  This issue is way more complicated than I though it would be.

Comment: "The function.caller property returns the function that invoked the specified function." (From the MDN Documentation). So you could just walk the backtrace to see if you find yourself. This won't work if you "use strict", BTW.

Comment: You can simply call the function again with an additional parameter, then within the same function, check for that parameter.

Comment: I edited completely my answer with a better solution

Comment: Another solution... Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you reflect on it, what you are getting makes perfect sense **because every function in your code is a single object**.
`caller` is a reference to that object and the latter is always the same and so they are its instance variables' values.

In other words, if a function is present more than once in the stack trace then it's "**caller**" *appears* to be always the most recent caller. That's why your function fails to go up the stack trace and ends in a infinite loop in the above case.

Let's make an example:

`a` => `b` => `c` => `d` => `b` => `e` => `checkRecursion`

The above is the stack trace that ends in `checkRecursion` at the deepest level.
`b` is called the first time from `a` the second time from `d`.
But what you get from `caller` is that `b` is always called from `d` !
It cannot have two callers because the object/function is always the same.

Climbing the stack trace you get
`e` <= `b` <= `d` <= `c` <= `b` **<=** `d` <= `c` <= `b` **<=** `d`...
You never reach `a`

---

To achieve what you need you may obtain the stack trace with another technique that, unfortunately, is not cross browser.

Below there is a modified version of `checkRecursion` that uses that technique. I tested it on Firefox, it doesn't work on Safari.

```
// returns true if the caller appears more than once
// in the stack trace

function checkRecursion()
{
    // the name of the calling function 

    var fname = checkRecursion.arguments.callee.caller.name;


    // obtain the stack trace ***not cross browser***
    // tested on Firefox

    var err = new Error();
    var stack = err.stack.split('\n');


    // returns true if the calling function appears more than once

    var i,n,cnt;
    n = stack.length;
    cnt = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if( fname == stack[i].substr(0,stack[i].indexOf('@')) )
        {
            cnt++;
            if( cnt > 1 )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if you return the result of another function, but that function ends up calling you recursively? As in, `return someFunc();`

Comment: in that case you need to store the value returned by `someFunc()` in a variable, decrement the counter, return the value stored in the variable

Comment: I edited completely the answer, the first solution proposed was too ugly.

Comment: We came up we similar solutions but I did find a very interesting bug.  See my question update.

Comment: Yes, `arguments.callee.caller` is reliable to obtain only the closest caller. It cannot be used to safely go up along the stack trace. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller), you can check which function invoked your function. Check it against the last caller to see if they're the same function.

```
var y = function() {
    console.log(this.lastCaller === y.caller);
    this.lastCaller = y.caller;
}
var x = function(i) {
    y();    
    if(i) {
        x(--i);
    }
}
x(3);
```

Outputs:

`false, true, true, true`

Comment: OP wrote: "I mean that the function could be anywhere in the recursion chain (the function doesn't have to be the direct invoker)"

Comment: @Paolo Ahh I see - I misread the question. Sounds like they're asking to see if a function is anywhere inside _any_ recursive function - not the recursive function itself.

Comment: Updated to reflect clarification by @Paolo

Comment: @megawac - Can you elaborate? That seems to contradict this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chrome Developer Tool (if you use chrome) and start a new "Timeline" audit.

If you filter the result to show only the functions, you should be able to find some functions called by time.

Another thing to try is a "profile" audit to collect JavaScript CPU Profile. If you see a function name with an high percentage, that means it's using more resources and it may also be called multiple times.